# Ajax - display 2 different json datas

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have my functionality working fine but I need to load 2 different json datas by clicking th buttons which will load different json datas

-javascript datas (by clicking javascript)

-html datas (by clicking html)

**my buttons:**

```js
$(function() {


  $('.js-url').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+javascript+",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));

        $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
          var html_to_append =
            '<div class="git-user col-4"><div class="name">' +
            items.name +
            '</div><img  class="image" src="' +
            items.owner.avatar_url +
            '" /><a class="repo" href="' +
            items.html_url +
            '">' +
            items.name +
            "</a></div>";
          $("#items-container").append(html_to_append);
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log(data);
      }


    });

  });

  $('.html-url').on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+html+",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));

        $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
          var html_to_append =
            '<div class="git-user col-4"><div class="name">' +
            items.name +
            '</div><img  class="image" src="' +
            items.owner.avatar_url +
            '" /><a class="repo" href="' +
            items.html_url +
            '">' +
            items.name +
            "</a></div>";
          $("#items-container").append(html_to_append);
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log(data);
      }


    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="">
      <a class="js-url" href="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+javascript+">Javascript</a>
      <a class="html-url" href="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+html+">html</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="items-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 <nav class="">
    <a class="js-url" href="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+javascript+">Javascript</a>
    <a class="html-url" href="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+html+">html</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: What's your question? It seems like you need to put your AJAX call into click handlers. You're just running it when the page is loaded, not when the user clicks on something.

Comment: @Barmar thanks, I've added the click event something like this you mean?

Comment: You're not doing the AJAX call in the click handlers. And `#js-url` and `#html-url` don't match anything in the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar I've edited my snippet could you please help me to understand how to handle the click in a better way?

Comment: @Barmar theoretically it should load a javascript datas by default, then the user could choose html or javascript on click

Comment: It seems to be working. What's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar is the best practice? and what about if I have to load one of them by default? like javascript?

Comment: I suggest you define a named function that does it. Then you can call that function by default when the page is loaded, and also when they click on the button.

Comment: @Barmar would you be able to help so I can give you the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in named functions, so you can call the same function by default and also when the user clicks.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.js-url').on("click", ajaxJS);
  $('.html-url').on("click", ajaxHTML);

  ajaxJS();

  function ajaxJS(e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+javascript+",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        var html_to_append = '';
        $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
          html_to_append +=
            '<div class="git-user col-4"><div class="name">' +
            items.name +
            '</div><img  class="image" src="' +
            items.owner.avatar_url +
            '" /><a class="repo" href="' +
            items.html_url +
            '">' +
            items.name +
            "</a></div>";
        });
        $("#items-container").html(html_to_append);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });

  }

  function ajaxHTML(e) {
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+html+",
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        var html_to_append = "";
        $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
          html_to_append +=
            '<div class="git-user col-4"><div class="name">' +
            items.name +
            '</div><img  class="image" src="' +
            items.owner.avatar_url +
            '" /><a class="repo" href="' +
            items.html_url +
            '">' +
            items.name +
            "</a></div>";
        });
        $("#items-container").html(html_to_append);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <nav class="">
      <a class="js-url" href="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+javascript+">Javascript</a>
      <a class="html-url" href="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+html+">html</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div id="items-container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it does. The new items are added after the default items, because you don't clear the container before you append the new ones.

Comment: `$("#items-container").empty();`

Comment: Or just use `.html()` instead of `.append()`.

Comment: inside  function ajaxJS(e) {} ?

Comment: why do I see only one item now? if you click them it displays one one item

Comment: I didn't realize the `append()` call was inside the loop. I've moved it outside of the loop, using `+=` in the loop to concatenate all the HTML strings first.

Answer (score 1):

I saved a lot of lines of code. Simple and easy!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('* .load-json').on('click', function(e) {
    var lang = $(this).data('lang');

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('href'),
      method: "GET",
      beforeSend: function() {
        $('#items-container .loading').html('Loading items - ' + lang);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        //$(".git-user").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        
        $('#items-container').html('');

        $.each(data.items, function(i, items) {
          var html_to_append =
            '<div class="git-user col-4"><div class="name">' +
            items.name +
            '</div><img  class="image" src="' +
            items.owner.avatar_url +
            '" /><a class="repo" href="' +
            items.html_url +
            '">' +
            items.name +
            "</a></div>";
          $("#items-container").append(html_to_append);
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <nav class="">
   <a class="load-json" href="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+javascript+" data-lang="javascript">Javascript</a>
   <a class="load-json" href="https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1+language:'+html+" data-lang="html">html</a>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div id="items-container">
      <div class="loading"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```